# Using google map and FCM in one react-native project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, npm, build.gradle

I want to use google map and FCM in one react native project , first I added FCM in project, everything was okay but when I added google map, I faced an error :
[image]

I googled a lot, there are so many answers that I have tried but none of them worked for me for example:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1230
, some one help me. I will provide some screen shoots of my project , if u need something else, let me know.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: I'm using the latest version of `react-native` (v0.56.0).

I have faced a lot of issues in using these libraries together and finally I've got this config, by using the configuration below I could build and run my project successfully:

`android/build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.0.2"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
}
```

`android/app/build.gradle` file:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2'
    implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.13.4'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
#Tue Aug 01 12:26:47 IRDT 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

And [this document](https://itnext.io/install-react-native-maps-with-gradle-3-on-android-44f91a70a395) is useful for installing `react-native-maps`.

Comment: thanks for your response , but when I use the latest version of react-native I face this problem .https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20015 . would u explain more about how to solve the issue

Comment: Are you using CRNA?

Comment: if by CRNA u mean create-react-native-app ,  yes I used the following command to create my project , Is there something wrong with it ?

Comment: No nothing is wrong but because I did't use CRNA and I inited my app natively I did'n face the issue you faced. Did you try my config with your `react-native` version? note that you should use the proper version of gradle.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to conflicts in the versions of Google Play Services being pulled in by fcm and map. You should try to use *project-wide gradle config.*

You also can read the configuration for one signal (it have the same function with firebase) to understand a little your problem or better you can open your project with android studio, you will see exactly problem.

```js
   compile('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1') {
        // Exclude com.android.support(Android Support library) as the version range starts at 26.0.0
        //    This is due to compileSdkVersion defaulting to 23 which cant' be lower than the support library version
        //    And the fact that the default root project is missing the Google Maven repo required to pull down 26.0.0+
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        // Keeping com.google.android.gms(Google Play services library) as this version range starts at 10.2.1
    }
```

Comment: Hi you can follow this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/. Actually, I just try to exclude all google play service in my project.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that react-native-map and firebae dependencies differ from each other so u need to use the same version of react-native-maps and firebase or any other API that u are using in your project