# Could not find method implementation() for arguments React Native Maps

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-maps

When i react-native run-android i get this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\xcrix\Desktop\projects\The Art Hunter\arthunterclient\android\build.gradle' line: 10
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'arthunterclient'.

  > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':react-native-maps', build_5yzom2lyrek7xvyvgp2oo4gzp$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure4@1d634cfe] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Android/build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'  
implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
   }
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

    }
}
```

Android/gradle.properties

```
android.enableAapt2=false
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Android/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'arthunterclient'

include ':app'
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
```

Android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile



project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arthunterclient"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
  }
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

I spent more than 5 hours to solve this problem.tried everything on internet but still same...

Comment: Hi. I know it might be late to respond 3 months later, but for anyone else who will visit this question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51257878/4031108) solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
```

remove it from `android/build.gradle`. keep it in `android/app/build.gradle` only